# Google Maps API response that seems to have changed

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I was launching tests of my TDD project when Gmaps tests started to fail. I checked and figured that they were sending an *f* for the `lng`and the `lat` instead of a string for `destination.location` and `origin.location`:

```
destination: {
  location: {
    lat: ƒ,
    lng: ƒ
  }
},
origin: {
  location: {
    lat: ƒ,
    lng: ƒ
  }
}
```

Does it require a token access (I've never been using it) or am I missing something?

Thanks!

[image: This is what Google Map now sends back]

Comment: What are you providing in your request?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.